# How to auto refresh the text of a button which is in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, textwatcher

My AlertDialog contains a `button` and `3 text fields` which are auto populated with some text when certain conditions are met.

When all the text fields are non-empty, I am changing the default text of the button to `Assign`.

The text is changed but in the UI, it is still showing the original text.

I am using class `TextWatcher` to watch the text in the three fields and to change the text of the button.

**My short code**:

```
private class LocalTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            //the three text fields
            String equipNumText = equipnumbertext.getText().toString().trim();
            String plateNumText = licenseplatetext.getText().toString().trim();
            String vinNumtext = vintext.getText().toString().trim();

            if(!equipNumText.equals("") && !plateNumText.equals("") && !vinNumtext.equals(""))
            {

                //the button
                lookupButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.lookupbtn);

                System.out.println("Default Button value"+lookupButton.getText()); //Look Up

                lookupButton.setText("Assign");

                //lookupButton.invalidate();
                //lookupButton.refreshDrawableState();

                System.out.println("Button value after change"+lookupButton.getText()); //Assign
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    }
```

Although my output shows that there is a change in the button value but my **AlertDialog UI** is not updated with the changes.

I also used `lookupButton.invalidate()` **OR/AND** `lookupButton.refreshDrawableState()` without success.

Comment: Sorry if this may seem nonsense, but are you sure `R.id.lookupbtn` is your AlertDialog button?. Can you show the code where and how this class is used

Answer (score 0):

It is quite strange but true that, the change in text triggers the call to overridden `onCreate()` method of the activity, which again sets the value of lookupButton to `Look Up`.

Having the following lines of code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.......
.......
TextWatcher watcher = new LocalTextWatcher();
equipnumbertext.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
licenseplatetext.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
vintext.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
lookupButton.setText("Look Up");
.......
.......
}

private class LocalTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        .......
        .......
}
```

On change in text of the three fields, the `onCreate()` method is getting called, which again sets the value of button to `Look Up`.